# three.js problems on iPhone (Safari), Issue with Texture Size?

Tags: iphone, object, three.js, textures, jpeg

i currently have an issue with my three.js Online viewer.  My Obj./Texture (jpg-File) combination does not open on my iPhone (Safari). It stops at 98% then restarts the download. This issue only happens with some files, so i am trying to find out, which characteristic of my file does cause the problem.
At my PC (Edge, Firefox and IE) all files open properly
The main differences of the working file and the not working file are:
Texture-jpg (working file): Size: 6MB, Resolution:2000x2000
Texture-jpg (non-working file): Size: 1,5MB, Resolution:8000x8000
Might the difference of the texture-Files be the reason for my issue?
Another difference is, that the working obj-File has a much lower scaling, even though the number of vertices is similar.
Would be great to hear some opinions.
Best Wishes
Gerd

Answer (score 0):

So let me qualify by saying that I don't know much about platform issues, and I'm quite new in general. But I do know that THREE.js doesn't like textures that aren't a factor of 2 and it'll convert it behind the scenes to make it work. It's probably changing it to a factor of two behind the scenes, and it may just dislike doing that over a certain size of image? Try changing it to 2048 or 8192 and see if it functions.

Comment: Yes, i will try that. I googled, that a size taller than 4096x4096 might be an issue at mobile devices. I am currently waiting for the new texture-file.

Comment: @gerdsattler you should post the solution (if it's just a texture size issue, then just put that in here) and mark it as solved if you manage to sort it out, to help out the community.  I would be interested to hear what the solution was as well :)

Comment: Yes, i will do that - but i could not test it yet. Give me some days ;-)

Comment: I did some testing now with a 4Kx4K texture. As assumes, this texture works good with mobile devices and (different Phones, MacBook Air, IPad). Even tough they only support a maximum size of 4096x4096 some of these devices can also handle the 8K texture. Well, in these cases the upload-time increases a lot.